# Multiple questions about the process of converting a website to an app

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, web-applications

I have a simple test website and I want to convert it to an app using some software.

1. Which converter is good to use? cordova, framework7, PhoneGap and...? I myself prefer to use cordova, what's your idea?
2. If I want not to use above converters and program it myself using Android Studio, how much time do I need to learn (not completely) to have a simple app?
3. Can I use jQuery and bootstrap instead of jQuery mobile for just styling and some Ajax call which is using only json? because I think I can do what animation/transition I want with jQuery and the styling with bootstrap. Is there any need for jQuery mobile?
4. Is jQuery excess when we can use JavaScript? Doesn't it load lots of data  not needed?

Comment: Well if your web app is mobile ready, then you can just create app with web view then show the web app inside it.

Comment: If you are creating a website which is responsive enough to load on mobile Just search on Google convert website url to apk it will generate apk for you.

Comment: Isn't web view slower than native one? If I use cordova, doesn't it create the native one?

Comment: No I don't want whole website to be converted to app. But there is an API in the site which I want to use it using ajax/json.

Comment: the question 2, do you mean to make a native app in Android?

Comment: @JoseRojas yes I meant native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Phonegap is based on Cordova, so both are similar. either you pick up gonna be similar.
2. If you're going to learn from scratch native Android and depending of complexity of the app, this could take a considerable time.
3. I've tested jQuery (not jQuery Mobile) in cordova applications, making AJAX callings and it worked well. So I don't see any problem to use it together with bootstrap for your project.
4. jQuery mobile gives you elements to make your app looks like a real native app, and if you download the whole package this is not so light, there is other option like ionic (this works with Angular).

Comment: 1. It is not the comparison between phonegap and cordova, but all the converters we can use.

Comment: 2. Could you tell min and max time needed?

Comment: 3. so it't better to use jQuery with jQuery mobile OR jQuery with bootstrap? how about Ionic? what is that? what are the diffrences?

Comment: 1. The only tools that I've used what you mentioned of in this point are those 2, there are others called Xamarin and NativeScript if you want to search them for. 2. The time is relative, depends of a lot of factors, e.g. your profiency with Java, previous experience with applications and so on. If you want to make a Hello World app this can take you 2 hours or less. 3. Ionic is continously being updated, the last version of this framework is current, on the other hand jQuery mobile the last stable  version available is 1.45 (https://jquerymobile.com/) this version is from october 2014

Comment: @needcode complemeting the point 3, in Ionic the patter MVC is easily implementable because this framework is based on Angular, so for large applications would be easily maintinable and editable. JQuery not, you must be pretty organized with your code if you don't want to have a mess

Comment: @needcode if my answer helps you, I'd appreciate to accept my post as answer